# Lock Screen UI with incoming Call

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on a video/audio call app. Now when my phone is locked and another user is calling me then from the lock screen I will get a notification and if I swipe the notification then the call automatically received. I used `UILocalNotification` for getting notification.

But I don't want like this. I want to see the UI same as when another user call me when my phone is unlocked that is there will be receive/reject option with my UI. I want to receive call like Viber or skype. How can I do that?

Comment: It's [**CallKit**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit) which you need to integrate!

Comment: Any link of tutorial in Objective C please?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ios+callkit+tutorials+in+objective+c&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: I have google about this. I didn't find good tutorial in Objective c. Most of the tutorials are in Swift. Thats why I asked for link. By the way thanks

Answer (score 5):

You should be looking into the `PushKit` framework form Apple.

> The PushKit framework provides the classes for your iOS apps to
>   receive VoIP pushes from remote servers. VoIP pushes provide the
>   functionality that VoIP apps need to perform on-demand processing of
>   the push before displaying a notification to the user.

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit)

There are some tutorials might help you.

[Tutorial 1](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ios/create-native-ios-app-can-receive-voip-push-notifications/)

[Tutorial 2](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/ios8-apps-and-pushkit/)

**Update**

To display the system-calling UI for your app's VoIP services you can use `CallKit`.

[CallKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit)

[Sample code from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html)

Here is a tutorial which explains it well.

http://www.techjini.com/blog/enhance-voip-app-user-experience-using-pushkit-callkit/

https://www.raywenderlich.com/150015/callkit-tutorial-ios

Comment: I used PushKit framework for doing that. My problem is I don't want incoming call like notification when my phone is locked. I want incoming call View like the View when my phone is unlocked.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood. You wan't to receive call like whatsapp or skype?

Comment: Yes, you got me.

Comment: See updated answer. Solution to your problem is `CallKit`

Comment: Any link of tutorial in Objective C?

Comment: it possible overlap screen add out coming call screen objective  c ?