# Open iOS (Flutter) app directly after answering VoIP call from locked iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, voip, callkit, pushkit

A project I'm working on works mainly around a good UI/UX. The one issue I'm facing is answering calls on a locked iOS device.

**Documentation:**

Apple introduced the [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit) and [PushKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit) features to allow access to the native call screen which is good, but not ideal in my case.

There is good literature on both of these components, e.g.

- [Receiving incoming calls](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit#2865219)
- [Responding to VoIP Notifications from PushKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/responding_to_voip_notifications_from_pushkit)
- [**Very useful iOS 13 PushKit restrictions**](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/117939)

**Previously asked?**

There are **many** questions about this issue, mostly centered around 2 years ago, which is why I am asking again.

- **Recommended with tutorials** - [Lock Screen UI with incoming Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493120/lock-screen-ui-with-incoming-call)
- [iOS - Can I open my VoIP app on answering call using Callkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740139/ios-can-i-open-my-voip-app-on-answering-call-using-callkit)
- [CallKit: Launch app when screen is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60596710/callkit-launch-app-when-screen-is-locked)
- https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep/issues/319#issuecomment-758628836

**Some extra CallKit/PushKit tutorials**

- https://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ios/create-native-ios-app-can-receive-voip-push-notifications/
- (Flutter Specific, can be used for native iOS too) https://github.com/masashi-sutou/flutter_ios_webrtc_kit
- https://www.raywenderlich.com/1276414-callkit-tutorial-for-ios
- https://agostini.tech/2019/06/23/receiving-incoming-calls-with-pushkit/
- https://learn.vonage.com/blog/2021/01/28/handling-voip-push-notifications-with-callkit/
- https://medium.com/@ykawanabe/system-calling-screen-with-callkit-77004b1224e5

The issue is non of these, as far as I have read, provide a mechanism to open an app directly after answering.

**Viable solutions**

The only way to do this with the current implementation is to use the last of the 6 buttons on the `CallKit` screen (optionally with an `AppIcon`), see image [Masked Image Icon]:

[image]

**Examples:**

- [GitHub example with App Icon & custom ring sound](https://github.com/opentok/CallKit)

**Question:**

I can't find any solution to open my iOS (Flutter app) when answering a VoIP call from a locked state - is this at all possible?

Comment: I am facing same problem did you found any solution for your question?

Comment: This isn't possible due to the CallKit used by iOS - this is simply they way they've implemented any and all call answering to standardize it across apps see Discord, WhatsApp, etc

Comment: On whatsapp after answering call app automatically open how it's possible during locked mode?

Comment: On Android yes, just tested and confirmed it is not the case with iOS. the CallKit is used and goes the the screen shown above. To go to WhatsApp, you have to press the Masked image icon (6th button)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you still need the solution, but for the sake of others finding this question: I found the answer in another Stackoverflow post.

Link: [iOS CallKit. Jump directly to application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71738256/ios-callkit-jump-directly-to-application)

I am copying the answer here for clarity (credits go to [0awawa0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14528242/0awawa0)) Note that the code example is in Swift.

> So apparently, if you set.   `hasVideo` property to true for your
> `CXCallUpdate` when reporting the call, system will automatically open
> your application when call is accepted. Anyway, this feature is not
> mentioned anywhere in the documentation. Or, at least, I can not find
> anything about it.
>
> Here is the part of my code that reports new call now:
>
> ```
> let update = CXCallUpdate()
> update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: handle)
> update.hasVideo = true // <- was false earlier, setting to true did the trick
> update.supportsDTMF = false
> update.supportsHolding = true
> update.supportsGrouping = false
> update.supportsUngrouping = false
>
> callProvider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update, completion { error in     /*...*/ }
> ```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. I've found an alternative solution via package plugins implemented for a specific VoIP provider instead that offers native call implementation.

Comment: no problem, I'm glad you made it work for you!

Comment: @CybeX Which plugin did you use for this solution?

Comment: @MobileWorld use twilio_voice

Comment: @CybeX, is it only the package `twilio_voice` you used or you make use of twilio service incombination??

i'm asking because i'm having same problem as you are and i'm using livekit.io for my one-on-one call

Comment: @Zionnite I unfortunately did not, atleast for iOS. This is intended via CallKit's framework to standardize call screens between apps. There unfortunately is no solution for this besides adding an AppIcon to direct the user to your app.

Comment: I found a way, i did it and it's working fine on my App.
ensure to put `hasVideo=true`, so when a user initiates a call, to an iPhone it always video because I set it in my params `callingScreen to be true` for iPhone, and while they are on the call my code looks out for callType either video or voice, so if the callType its Voice, the user would navigate to the voice or video.

so making the Calling Params have Video forces the CallKit to open the app